# How not to expand `*` upon view creation

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I created a view in like this:

```
create view MyView as
select field1,
       field2,
       table2.*
from table1 join table2 ....
```

The problem is that when I add new column to table2, it will not appear in the view. When I do `show create view MyView`, I see the fields of table2 expanded in the query, instead of `table2.*` being kept there.

How can I force MySQL not to expand `*` upon view creation, but postpone this expansion for query run?

PS: just being curious, in case MySQL can't do this, do other databases like PostgreSQL etc. allow this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because MySQL expands all tables (defines their fields) on view creation, that is behavior.

You may check it just after creation using `SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name` statement.

So, you need to recreate your view.

Comment: Ad first too paragraphs - did you read my question? Seems like you just repeat what I state there.

Comment: The answer is - no, it is not possible. This is MySQL behavior.